# MySQL insert error in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've been trying to get the code below to execute, although no error appears, the row is not inserted when I check the result in the Database. There seems to be a problem in passing $query into $sql, because when I echo the same value of $query and add it as text into $sql it works fine.

any idea what is the error ?

```
$i=3;

$query = '"'."INSERT INTO data (ID,QN,QI,CB,BK,QK)".""."VALUES("."'".$i."','".$price[17]."','".$price[47]."','".$price[77]."','".$price[107]."','".$price[137]."')".'"';

echo $query;

$connect= mysql_connect("localhost", "urs" , "password") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("data", $connect);

$sql= $query; 

mysql_query($sql,$connect)
```

Comment: Why are you even copying $query into $sql?

Comment: `'"'."` what is dat?! if you tried to enter `"` symbol, you should do it this way: "\"INSERT....\"";. Also there is no need for it in this case. Could be simply "INSERT....";

Comment: You need to read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) so you don’t create any more severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) like the one you have here. Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and is a safer way to compose queries. What you're doing here is highly error prone and very hard to do correctly.

Comment: **Building SQL statements with outside variables makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.** Also, any input data with single quotes in it, like "O'Malley", will blow up your query. Learn about parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) has many detailed examples. See also http://bobby-tables.com/php for alternatives & explanation of the danger. **Running SQL statements built with outside data is like eating soup made from ingredients found on your doorstep.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your query has no space right before `VALUES` which would make the query syntactically incorrect as far as MySQL goes. It would render like this when the script runs:

```
INSERT INTO data (ID,QN,QI,CB,BK,QK)VALUES(…);
```

MySQL would choke on that query. Instead, try this version of your query with one space added before the `VALUES`:

```
$query = '"'."INSERT INTO data (ID,QN,QI,CB,BK,QK)".""." VALUES("."'".$i."','".$price[17]."','".$price[47]."','".$price[77]."','".$price[107]."','".$price[137]."')".'"';
```

But that said, your concatenation makes 100% no sense & is unnecessarily complex. I’ve cleaned that up & this should work:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO data (ID,QN,QI,CB,BK,QK) VALUES('$i','$price[17]','$price[47]','$price[77]','$price[107]','$price[137]');";
```

The key you need to understand is double quotes in PHP allow for string substation. So no need to concatenate to the degree you did.

Also you are missing a semi-colon after the `mysql_query()` so it should be like this:

```
mysql_query($sql,$connect);
```

So here is my cleaned up version of your code:

```
// Set the value for `$1`.
$i = 3;

// The query.
$query = "INSERT INTO data (ID,QN,QI,CB,BK,QK) VALUES('$i','$price[17]','$price[47]','$price[77]','$price[107]','$price[137]');";

// Set the connection or die returning an error.
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "urs" , "password") or die(mysql_error());

// Select the database;
mysql_select_db("data", $connect);

// Run the query or die returning an error.
mysql_query($query, $connect) or die(mysql_error());
```

But now really looking at it you are selecting a database named `data` and then inserting into a table within that database called `data` as well? Is that correct? Seems like you might have mixed up the idea of a database & a table so double check that.

Also note that I added an `or die(mysql_error());` after `mysql_query($query, $connect)`. Your first `or die(mysql_error());` only covers errors in the connection & not errors that would appear when the query runs. Now if the query has an error, it will die with an error being returned.

That said, you should explore using `mysqli_*` commands instead of `mysql_*` since `mysql_*` commands are depreciated in PHP 5.3 to 5.4 and are completely eliminated in PHP 5.5.

Comment: Thank you <3 that made it work .. I can see clearly what I got wrong